# Canceling multiple SoftLayer Instances thru the API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is there a way using the API to cancel multiple instances with out looping through a for loop?

We are currently using a for loop to do this and we are exploring other ways to get the devices canceled.

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

Nop, unfortunately, it's not possible to cancel multiple instances, doing a single call, the best way is to use "for" loop as you did.